# Dockerize a angular SSR application

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, server-side-rendering

I am a newbie to Docker so please bear it with me.
I am trying to dockerize my Angular SSR application.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
It's keep saying 502 Bad gateway. First, it was displaying nginx default page. Then I updated the nginx conf and now it is saying 502.
I am running it on 4000:80 port. I have also tried exposing the port in dockerfile but to no avail.
Any idea where I am messing up?
I have attached my dockerfile, nginx conf and the error I am facing.

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build-step
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build:ssr
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]
#Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/front-end-kevi /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Here is my nginx conf.

```
events {}
http
{
server {
    index index.php index.hh index.html index.htm;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
    }
    location /OrderMationApiDev/ {
      proxy_pass http://102.133.225.222/OrderMationApiDev/;
    }
    }
    }
```

Error I am facing

> [error] 7#7: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/favicon.ico", host: "localhost:4000", referrer: "http://localhost:4000/"

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Mate I have added my code. can you please elaborate more what do you mean by "You don't have a node running in that stage". Thank you in advance.

Comment: Great! Now I see the CMD .  Do you want deploy your app or develop from docker ?

Comment: I want to build my docker image and deploy it. @Mate

Comment: Ok.  Do you want to use build:ssr and not build:prerender ?

Comment: The first container (build-stage) is discarded after copying. What you are doing is building the app in build-stage, copying it into stage 2 and creating an image from this. Afterwards you are starting the new image with run (which only contains stage 2 and the copied files). There is no nodejs in this image. Either you mean by SSR that you only have static files (nginx should directly serve the files) or you need something like docker compose to run 2 containers (nginx and node). Right now localhost:4000 is nothing.

Comment: you forgot to publish/expose ports. i would suggest you to create a compose file where these two service can talk to each other while running separately. https://ashwin9798.medium.com/nginx-with-docker-and-node-js-a-beginners-guide-434fe1216b6b